# How to query property keys with conditions in LoopBack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

How to query the key values of properties in LoopBack? In my case, the keys are array of objects.

The schema I generated is,

```
{
"bookingsLog": [
      {
        "checkIn": 1456079400000,
        "checkOut": 1456165800000
      },
      {
        "checkIn": 1456079400000,
        "checkOut": 1456165800000
      }
    ]
}
```

The remote method used to query is,

```
Resort.search = function(custom, cb) {}
Resort.remoteMethod('search', {
    accepts: {
        arg: 'custom',
        type: 'object',
        http: function(ctx) {
            var _cIn = ctx.req.body.checkIn;
            var _cOut = ctx.req.body.checkOut;
            Resort.find({
                where: {
                    and: [{ checkIn: { neq: _cIn } }, { checkOut: { neq: _cOut } },
                        { checkIn: { neq: { between: [_cIn, _cOut] } } },
                        { checkOut: { neq: { between: [_cIn, _cOut] } } }
                    ]
                }
            }, function(err, resorts) {
                console.log('Length is = ' + resorts.Length);
                console.log('Res is = ' + JSON.stringify(resorts));
                if(err){return ctx.res.send(err);}
                if(resorts){return ctx.res.send(resorts);}
            });
        }
    },
    returns: {
        arg: 'custom',
        type: 'object'
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While asking question on SO, you should give the best information that you can provide, along with the things that you have tried, from your Question, nothing is clear, that what are the models, what is a sample document.